# How to skip the zero value in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to handle an array of object. Where, I wanna ignore the object which has the value of '0' and print the values which is greater than zero by looping through 'storyIds', any ideas.

```
var dataArr = [
 {number: 1, workId: [0], storyIds: [0]},
 {number: 2, workId: [0], storyIds: [0]},
 {number: 3, workId: [1], storyIds: [10]},
 {number: 4, workId: [2], storyIds: [10]},
 {number: 5, workId: [3], storyIds: [20]}
];
```

**Expected Output**

```
3, 4, 5 //Output
```

Comment: you want to *filter* out the elements in the array where something has a particular value ... array has a *`filter`* method that can be used for just such an occasion - a good source of documentation for such things is on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/bm/docs/Web/JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

```js
var dataArr = [
 {number: 1, workId: [0], storyIds: [0]},
 {number: 2, workId: [0], storyIds: [0]},
 {number: 3, workId: [1], storyIds: [10]},
 {number: 4, workId: [2], storyIds: [10]},
 {number: 5, workId: [3], storyIds: [20]}
];

console.log(dataArr.filter((v) => !!v.storyIds[0]))
```